# Flask SECRET_KEY & Password Hashing

Tags: python, security, flask, werkzeug, password-hash

In case there is a breach in your webapp and you must replace its SECRET_KEY.
Could users still log-in with their passwords?

In other words, does the "password hashing" process relies on your webapp SECRET_KEY to encode/ decode passwords?
If so, isn't it makes all passwords that were set before useless (after changing the SECRET_KEY)?

Answer (score -1):

No, Flask does not hash your passwords. You do. In the improbable case that you use the SECRET_KEY to hash your passwords, your passwords would potentially be unusable. But you don't normally do that. Normally you hash using werkzeug's [generate_password_hash](https://github.com/Abdur-rahmaanJ/shopyo/blob/dev/shopyo/modules/admin/models.py#L77) or using something such as [bcrypt](https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I'm using werkzeug's library to do so. But isn't it relies on the app secret? If not how it works?

Comment: @Idos: the source: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/543d1340706741a6107535f93d734395caba7082/src/werkzeug/security.py#L159